# Solution for the parallel execution of tests that verify email

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-strategy, email, parallel-execution

I have a test, that reads `Auth Code` from mailbox and uses it to log in. I use `Gmail API` for that.

I would like to have several such tests, that will run in parallel.

However, I don't know, how to distinguish emails from each other, because the only thing, that is different about 2 emails is this `Auth Code`.

So, `race condition` looks like this:

1. `test-1` sends an email at `00:00:00`
2. `test-2` sends an email at `00:00:01`
3. it takes `3 seconds` for the `email-1` to arrive => `00:00:03`,
4. it takes only `1 second` for the `email-2` to arrive => `00:00:02`
5. `test-1` reads the first unread matching email, and it is an `email-2`

`Result`: `Auth code` is wrong.

So, my question here is:

could you please think of any possible solution to avoid such a race condition and identify the email?

Comment: Didn't you consider using different emails for different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use different e-mail accoouns for this (of course if you are not going to test the case when user try to login two times and mix codes/use proper codes from two messages e.g. on 2 devices)?

Comment: How about using Gmails wildcard feature "myname+randomWildcard@gmail.com" and then distinguish based on "randomWildcard"?

Answer (score 0):

Some email providers let you use "+" on the email address, e. g. "johndoe+abc123@example.com" that you can use to differentiate the different sources.

Is the information on the source of the email buried in the headers that you can hunt?

Can your devs embed a hidden element in the page you see immediately after the email is sent, then include either a similar hidden element in the email? Or in a header? Bonus points if they can do this only on your testing systems, or if you can change the URL to add a query string parameter to trigger adding the debug information?